# how to run java 7 project in eclipse neon 2?

Tags: eclipse, java-8, java-7, m2eclipse, eclipse-neon

my project was built in java 7.i have to run that project in neon 2. so I installed java 7 but when I start the eclipse it shows the error and eclipse terminated.
error: Version 1.7.0_79 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. version:1.8 or greater is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open eclipse.ini and add

```
-vm
path_to_your_jdk8/bin/javaw.exe
```

Note: do this before **-vmargs**

In project properties ,in compiler options change compiler to java 8 and build the project ..

Comment: Thanks @Frank its work for my eclipse, but can you tell me that if I open my project then it will store in 7 or converting into JAVA 8?

Comment: do you have JDK 7 installed?

Comment: yes. both were installed.but I set the path of java 7.

Comment: In project properties in java build path did you set JRE System library to java 7 and in compiler java 7 too ?